# Get and use the user group name in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, usergroups

I am only using Wordpress with Woocommerce. Is there a way to get user **group name** based on logged in user's info?

I have group of users called 'Group1' and assigned 2 users to it - user1, user12

I have the second group of users called 'Group2' and assigned 2 users to it - user2 and user23.

Now I need to check from which user group is the logged in user (all users have the same role - Customers).

Here is the sample of the code of what I am trying to do:

```
$user_logged = wp_get_current_user();
$user_group_name = // how to get user_logged's group name ?
if ($user_group_name == 'Group1') // do 1st
if ($user_group_name == 'Group2') // do 2nd
```

Names of the groups will be not changed so I will put them as strings into the code. However I need to get dynamically after user loggs in the name of the group he is assigned to.

How can I do it ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Nobody can really know what are your user groups with the provided information in your question. You should update your question giving more details about the related plugin used for your user groups and about how is saved that 'Group1' or 'Group2' in the database table `wp_usermeta`. WordPress and Woocommerce don't provide any usergroup functionality by default.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I had wp-members plugin installed. All of the answers below were very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost made it. Based on documentation, [wp_get_current_user()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_current_user) return [WP_User](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) object that has properties **roles** (the roles the user is part of).

```
$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

if (in_array("Group1", $roles)) {
   // do 1st
}
if (in_array("Group2", $roles)) {
   // do 2nd
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Use `wp_get_current_user()->roles` to retrieve the groups the user is a member of.

```
$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

if (in_array('group1',$roles)) {
    echo 'Do something here for group 1';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to know what the role of an online user is?

Finally, you should use the following code.

```
$get = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'administrator', $get->roles ) )
    // do 1st
if ( in_array( 'editor', $get->roles ) )
    // do 2st
if ( in_array( 'group1', $get->roles ) )
    // do 3st
if ( in_array( 'groupN', $get->roles ) )
    // do N st
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use easily and directly [`current_user_can()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/current_user_can/) WordPress dedicated function with a specific user role (or a user capability) like:

```
if ( current_user_can( 'Group1' ) ) {
    // do 1st
} elseif ( current_user_can( 'Group2' ) ) {
    // do 2st
}
```

> WordPress and Woocommerce don't provide any Usergroup functionality by default. What related plugin are you using for those Usergroups. 
>   You need to search in the database table `wp_usermeta` to see if 'Group1' or 'Group2' are assigned to users and give us the meta_key used for it.